# Multiselects generating similar ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple multiselects on my page. On a button click a pop up is created which also has multiselects. On choosing options on the multiselect on the pop up then the multiselects in the background also get set . Although if the user unchecks  the values in the pop up multiselect, the multiselect on the page still retains the selections. 
It seems that the multiselects are generating the same ids at run time. 
HHow can this be solved?

Comment: post you code plz

Comment: You have to post the code and if possible, what you have tried to solve the problem